# load function not working in safari or chrome in one webpage but works in a test page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I am using a load function to load text into my my webpage. The text was initially hard coded into the page but i am slowly transferring  it all into a text file using the load function. 
   my issue is that when I attempt to load a test file in no page it only works in firefox but works in firefox chrome and safari in the other so it is definitely an issue with the code.

Here is the code that works

```
     !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p  align="left" class="our_goal_text" style="text-indent: 5em">Our goal text</p>

 <script> $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".our_goal_text").load("our_goal.txt");
  });
 </script>



</body>

</html>
```

and here is the one that doesn't work. The Load script is all the way at the bottom and the text file is supposed to be inserted in the second tabbed panel content named about us. There a "who are we. text" and and "out goals.text"

very odd but i ruled out my internet settings because I made an untitled page (code above) an tested it and it ran fine therefore somehow the load script isn't compatible with safari or chrome.

Thanks

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title></title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

<!--stylesheet-->
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="master">
    <div id="Header">
        <div id="logoholder">
            <div id="socialmedia">
<!-- START SOCIAL MEDIA WIDGET -->
<ul id="socialbar"><li id="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/username"><IMG src="ToneOnTone-Square-SocialIcons/ToneOnTone-Square-48x48/48x48-Square-34-FB copy.png"></a></li><li id="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/username"><IMG src="ToneOnTone-Square-SocialIcons/ToneOnTone-Square-48x48/48x48-Square-34-TW copy.png"></a></li><li id="feed"><a target="_blank" href="http://username.featuredblog.com/?feed=rss2"><IMG src="ToneOnTone-Square-SocialIcons/ToneOnTone-Square-48x48/48x48-Square-34-RSS copy.png"></a></li><li id="youtube"><a target="_blank" href="http://youtube.com/username"><IMG src="ToneOnTone-Square-SocialIcons/ToneOnTone-Square-48x48/48x48-Square-34-YT copy.png"></a></li></ul><style>#socialbar img {border:0px;}#socialbar li img {width:40px; height:40px;}#socialbar li a:hover {position:relative;top:2px;}#socialbar{padding:0px;list-style: none outside none; margin:0px; position: static;}#socialbar li {display:inline;padding-right:10px;}#socialbar{width:250px;text-align:center;}</style>
<!-- END SOCIAL MEDIA WIDGET--> 
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="Menuboxcontainer"><div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab notabboarder "tabindex="0">Home</li>
        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">About</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Programs</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Get Involved</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Upcoming Events</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Contact</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">

        <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"><div class="slideshow">
            <!--
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="container">
                    -->
     <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>

          <div id="slider">
 <div><img src="Pictures/girlnurse.jpg" alt="face1" width = 100%/><div id="textbox_register">
 <h3 class="h4">Support H.E.E.D LIFE</h3>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>Join the Fight Against Cancer</p>
   <p>in New Jersey.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>Become a member</p>
   <p class="redtext">Register and Login Now!</p>
 </div></div>

 <div><img src="Pictures/oldman.jpg" width=100% alt="face2"/>
 <div id="textbox_perks">
 <h3 class="h4">Screening Saves Lives</h3>
 <p>Your odds of defeating cancer are greater when it is detected  in its early stages.</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>Sigh up and learn about our</p><p class="redtext">FREE!</p><p> screening program.</p>
</div></div> 

 <div><img src="pictures/mamadukes.jpg" alt="face3"width= 100% />
   <div id="textbox_perks">
     <h3 class="h4">Learn about our programs</h3>
     <p class="redtext">Free Screenings for:</p>
     <p>Breast</p><p>Colorectal</p><p>Prostate</p><p> and lung cancers</p>
     <p class="redtext">Copay Assistance Program</p>
  <p> and Various Health Evaluation Events</p>


   </div>
 </div>
           </div>

        <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
                <!--</div>
            </div>
            -->   
          </div>
      </div>

    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">

    <div id="panelsbackground">
        <div id="opaquebackground"><div id="aboutustext">
<table  align="left" width="900" border="0" cellspacing=".25">
  <tr>
    <td width="200"><h3  align="center">
      <img src="whitelogo1.jpg" width="190" height="150" /></td></h3>

    <td width="600" height="200"><h3 align="left">Who are we</h3> <hr class="faded" />
    <p  align="left" class="Who_are_we_text" style="text-indent: 5em;">Who are we text</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="200"></td>
    <td width="600" align="left"><h3 align="left">Our goal</h3><hr class="faded" width="200" />
    <p  align="left" class="our_goal_text" style="text-indent: 5em">Our goal text</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
        </div></div></div></div>

 <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
  <div id="panelsbackground">
        <div id="opaquebackground"><div id="aboutustext">

</table>

<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing=".25">
  <tr>
    <td><table  width="750" border="0"  cellspacing=".025" align="left" vspace="20">
  <tr><h3 align="center">Programs</h3></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><h3>Community events<hr class="faded" /></h3></td>
    <td><h3>Health Awareness<hr class="faded" /></h3></td>
    <td><h3>Cancer prevention<hr class="faded" /><h3></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
</table>


 </div></div></div></div>



 <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"><div id="panelsbackground"><div id="opaquebackground"><div id="getinvolvedtext">
 <h2 align="center"> How Can You Help</h2><hr class="faded"/>
 <h3 align="center">Become a Member</h3><p align="center"></p>
 <h3 align="center">Volunteer</h3><p align="left"></p>
 <h3 align="center">Spread the word</h3><p align="left"></p>
<h3 align="center"> Suggestions</h3><p align="left"></p>
 </div></div></div></div>
<div class="TabbedPanelsContent"><div id="panelsbackground"><div id="opaquebackground"><h2 align="center">Upcoming Events</h2><hr class="faded"/></div></div></div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"><div id="panelsbackground"><div id="opaquebackground">
  <div id="contactusboxright"></div>
  </div></div></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="contentboxcontainer">
<div class="contentboxLeft"><h1 align="center">Our Affiliates</h1><hr class="faded" /></div>
<div class="contentboxCenter"><h1 align="center">Free Screenings Across NJ</h1><hr class="faded" /></div>
 <div class="contentboxRight"><h1 align="center" >News Letter</h1><hr class="faded" /></div>
<div id="footer">Address.Telephone.Email</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--picture cycle javascript-->
<script src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#slider').cycle({ 
            fx:    'fade', 
            speed:  'fast', 
            next:   '#next', 
            prev:   '#prev' 
          });
        </script>
 <!--tabbed panel javascript-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
  </script>-->
  <!--about us text: who are we-->
  <script type>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Who_are_we_text").load("Who_are_we.txt");
  });
 </script>
   <!--about us text: our goal-->
 <script> $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".our_goal_text").load("our_goal.txt");
  });
 </script>   
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: You are loading jquery twice. You can also put both $().load's under the same $(document).ready function

Comment: the loading query twice just allows me to use it when I'm not on the wifi it doesn't really effect anything negatively.

Comment: If your asking for help, you should post correct code. Loading jQuery twice is 100% wrong, period, and on top of that you have two different versions in your script!! If you want to have it available offline use some code like this '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>'

Comment: ok. fyi i learned how to code on youtube so go easy on me. all I'm saying is that loading jquery twice is not the source of this problem because I have removed each one separately and nothing happened. I even pasted both onto the test script and it still worked.

Comment: Go easy? It doesn't matter where you learned to code,someone pointing out  mistakes in your coding and giving you a way to code it is not being hard on someone. It is offering help. This is a coding site, BTW.